# Ruby string interpolation with substitution

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation

I have a given method that adds keys to urls with:

```
url % {:key => key}
```

But for  one url I need the key to be escaped with CGI.escape. I cannot change the method, I can only change the url, but substitution does not work:

```
"https://www.example.com?search=#{CGI.escape(%{key})}"
```

Is there a way to achieve this only by changing the url string? I cannot use additional variables or change the method, thus I cannot do the escaping in the method and send the escaped key to the url string.

Comment: Why doesn’t it work? What’s the error? And why can’t you change the code ways you deem sensible?

Comment: The result is just literally "key" ("https://www.example.com?search=key") no matter what value key has. Changing the method for a hard coded special case would decrease maintainability.

Comment: The only alternative I could think of is to add "if link == example.com ..." to the method and somehow add a note to the url string, like "Attention, the key for this url is escaped at method x. If you change the url, make sure escaping still works." To me this seems to be the worst possible solution.

Comment: Show an actual assignment to *url*, and what the correct output should be. You clearly have a problem, but no one can fix it for you without valid testable examples.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear how your given method is supposed to work. Can you give an example where the method works, and one where it doesn't? Ignoring the method part of your question, and focusing on the URL bit,

```
>> key = "Baby Yoda"
=> "Baby Yoda"
>> %{key}
=> "key"
```

is the expected result, regardless of whether you have a variable named key, set to any value. See: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation

Unless you have a method defined which overloads '%' to do something else special for URLs, but that isn't clear in your question.

If you just want to CGI escape the value of 'key' within your URL string, don't use the percent notation:

```
>> key = 'Baby Yoda'
=> "Baby Yoda"
>> "https://www.example.com?search=#{CGI.escape(key)}"
=> "https://www.example.com?search=Baby+Yoda"
```

Answer (score 0):

It just seems not possible. I worked around by defining a syntax ${...}

```
"https://www.example.com?search=${CGI.escape(%{key})}"
```

Then I first do subtitution of %{key} and then use eval to do CGI.Escape (or any method for that matter) with

```
gsub(/\${(.+?)}/) { |e| eval($1) }
```